# Kivy App working on pc but not in android

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I have made an apk by converting .py kivy with the help of buidozer in google colab. The earlier versions were working but now latest version is not working.

May be there is a problem in my .spec file so I am attaching it ...

At first I think my assest(images) are causing this problem but after removing them too it's not working.

I have done some research and got this `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat` but I don't know how to execute and use this command....

.spec file link : https://github.com/AyushRaj0305/APP/blob/main/.spec

All I want is that my apk should work in android

Thanks for Help

Comment: May be problem in .spec file requirements, you should do **pip freeze** in your current folder power shell to know which module is used for your application

Comment: I have matched the versions of kivy and kivymd and they both matched ....do I have to also use version for python3 in .spec??

Comment: Yes, like **python3==3.7.8**

Comment: Changing version didn't resolve the problem Devam...

Comment: do you created .apk file like this [link](https://github.com/Spidy20/Python_To_APK/blob/5a5f8b4a8926b6e401f1745ab4dd828fe559642e/android_app.ipynb) ?

Comment: yes , only one code differs.....I have used 2nd method on this [site](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-convert-python-app-into-apk-77f4c9cd55af)

Comment: can you send .apk file or you try to install the app in lower version of android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241383/discussion-between-ayush-raj-and-devam-sanghvi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same issue in past and I solve by adding requirements in .spec

This requirements work for me:

```
requirements = hostpython3==3.7.8,python3==3.7.8,kivy==1.11.1, certifi,chardet, lxml, docutils, future, idna, Kivy-Garden, Pygments, requests, six, soupsieve, urllib3, deep-translator, arabic-reshaper, python-bidi, openssl, pyopenssl, numpy, pytz, python-dateutil, pandas, setuptools, zope.interface, datetime
```

you have to write all modules and parent module in requirements which your app is using.

To know module which you app is using has two method:

1. run command **pip freeze** in current app folder in powershell
2. install all the module as below photo which help to install your application module

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8bCE.png]

I have debugged your code and found missing PIL

Comment: Hey bro! can you help me with this [que](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70871183/why-my-image-is-on-the-toolbar-not-below-it-in-kivy)