# Kivy app Crashing when using Instaloader module Android

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, instaloader

I wrote an app that uses Instaloader and kivy and added all the requirments to the buildozer.spec file

buildozer.spec requirements:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,pillow,requests,urllib3,certifi,chardet,idna,android,pyjnius,six,cython,instaloader
```

When I open the app the app crashes with a ModuleNotFoundError:

```
2022-03-03 16:12:46.522 4785-4835/com.example.instatools I/python: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-03 16:12:46.522 4785-4835/com.example.instatools I/python:   File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 4, in <module>
2022-03-03 16:12:46.522 4785-4835/com.example.instatools I/python:   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/instatools/instaloader/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
2022-03-03 16:12:46.522 4785-4835/com.example.instatools I/python:   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/instatools/instaloader/instaloader.py", line 24, in <module>
2022-03-03 16:12:46.522 4785-4835/com.example.instatools I/python:   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/instatools/instaloader/nodeiterator.py", line 7, in <module>
2022-03-03 16:12:46.522 4785-4835/com.example.instatools I/python:   File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
2022-03-03 16:12:46.522 4785-4835/com.example.instatools I/python:   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
2022-03-03 16:12:46.522 4785-4835/com.example.instatools I/python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
2022-03-03 16:12:46.522 4785-4835/com.example.instatools I/python: Python for android ended.
```

Comment: I had added this requirements `requirements = hostpython3==3.7.8,python3==3.7.8,kivy==1.11.1, certifi,chardet, lxml, docutils, future, idna, Kivy-Garden, Pygments, requests, six, soupsieve, urllib3, deep-translator, arabic-reshaper, python-bidi, openssl, pyopenssl, numpy, pytz, python-dateutil, pandas, setuptools, zope.interface, datetime` in my project solve the problem.Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70845537/kivy-app-working-on-pc-but-not-in-android)

Comment: @DevamSanghvi it didn't work for me, still the same error