# How to fix Kivy Android app stuck on presplash screen?

Tags: python, android, kivy, adb, buildozer

I am programing an Android App using the Python package Kivy. I have compiled an apk using buildozer and tested it on a virtual device using the emulator of Android studio - everything worked fine.

Now I wanted to use it on the target device for the project, a RealWear Navigator 500. Installing and starting the app works fine. However, it gets stuck on the presplash screen and then does nothing anymore. Here is the relevant logcat output.

```
...
08-26 14:24:01.869  1593  2291 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=tud.jonass.gaugechecker/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} from uid 10086
08-26 14:24:01.882  1593  3732 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
08-26 14:24:01.886  1593  2852 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
08-26 14:24:01.888   765  2141 D audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: enter: stream(0xeaac21a0)usecase(1: low-latency-playback) devices(0x2) is_haptic_usecase(0)
08-26 14:24:01.888   765  2141 D audio_hw_primary: select_devices for use case (low-latency-playback)
08-26 14:24:01.888   765  2141 D msm8974_platform: set_output_device:select_output_speaker=0,select_output_headphones=0 select_output_bluetooth=0
08-26 14:24:01.888   765  2141 D msm8974_platform: platform_get_output_snd_device: exit: snd_device(speaker) 2
08-26 14:24:01.888   765  2141 I msm8974_platform: platform_check_and_set_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: bitwidth 16, samplerate 48000 channels 2, backend_idx 0 usecase = 1 device (speaker)
08-26 14:24:01.888   765  2141 I msm8974_platform: platform_check_and_set_codec_backend_cfg: new_snd_devices[0] is 2
08-26 14:24:01.888   765  2141 I msm8974_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: bitwidth 16, samplerate 48000 channels 2, backend_idx 0 usecase = 1 device (speaker)
08-26 14:24:01.891   765  2141 D msm8974_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: updated afe: bitwidth 16, samplerate 48000 channels 2,backend_idx 0 usecase = 1 device (speaker)
08-26 14:24:01.891   765  2141 I msm8974_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: Codec selected backend: 0 updated bit width: 16 and sample rate: 48000
08-26 14:24:01.891   765  2141 D audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: force routing 0
08-26 14:24:01.891   765  2141 D audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: (87) check_usecases curr device: speaker, usecase device: backends match 0
08-26 14:24:01.891  1593  2291 E ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start
08-26 14:24:01.891   765  2141 D audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: (87) check_usecases curr device: speaker, usecase device: backends match 0
08-26 14:24:01.891   765  2141 D audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: check_usecases num.of Usecases to switch 0
08-26 14:24:01.891   765  2141 D hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
08-26 14:24:01.891   765  2141 D audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
08-26 14:24:01.891   765  2141 D msm8974_platform: platform_get_island_cfg_on_device:island cfg status on snd_device = (speaker 0)
08-26 14:24:01.891   765  2141 I soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_device_status: device 0x2 of type 0 for Event 1, with Raise=0
08-26 14:24:01.891   765  2141 D audio_route: Apply path: speaker
08-26 14:24:01.896  1593  2291 E ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start
08-26 14:24:01.901   765  2141 D soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: uc_info->id 1 of type 0 for Event 3, with Raise=0
08-26 14:24:01.901   765  2141 D audio_hw_utils: audio_extn_utils_send_app_type_cfg: usecase->out_snd_device speaker
08-26 14:24:01.901   765  2141 I audio_hw_utils: send_app_type_cfg_for_device PLAYBACK app_type 69937, acdb_dev_id 14, sample_rate 48000, snd_device_be_idx 41
08-26 14:24:01.903   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audio_cal, acdb_id = 14, path = 0, app id = 0x11131, sample rate = 48000, use_case = 0,buffer_idx_w_path =0, afe_sample_rate = 48000, cal_mode = 1, offset_index = 0
08-26 14:24:01.903   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_asm_topology
08-26 14:24:01.903   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TOPOLOGY_ID
08-26 14:24:01.903   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_adm_topology
08-26 14:24:01.903   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TOPOLOGY_ID
08-26 14:24:01.903   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audtable
08-26 14:24:01.903   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE
08-26 14:24:01.903   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE
08-26 14:24:01.903   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_CAL cal_type[11] acdb_id[14] app_type[69937]
08-26 14:24:01.903   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audvoltable
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_GAIN_DEP_STEP_TABLE_SIZE
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D android.hardware.audio.service: Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000000E 
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_GAIN_DEP_STEP_TABLE_SIZE Returned = -19
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_GAIN_DEP_STEP_TABLE, vol index 0
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D android.hardware.audio.service: Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000000E 
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_VOL_CAL cal type = 12
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_STREAM_TABLE_SIZE
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audstrmtable
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_STREAM_TABLE
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> audstrm_cal->cal_type.cal_data.cal_size = 20
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_topology
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_TOPOLOGY_ID
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> GET_AFE_TOPOLOGY_ID for adcd_id 14, Topology Id 112fc
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_cal
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D android.hardware.audio.service: Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000000E 
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE Returned = -19
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D android.hardware.audio.service: Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000000E 
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AFE_CAL cal_type[16] acdb_id[14]
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_hw_delay : acdb_id = 14 path = 0
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_AVSYNC_INFO: ACDB_CMD_GET_DEVICE_PROPERTY
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply mixer and update path: low-latency-playback
08-26 14:24:01.904   765  2141 D audio_route: Apply path: low-latency-playback
08-26 14:24:01.906   765  2141 D audio_hw_primary: select_devices: done
08-26 14:24:01.906   765  2141 D msm8974_platform: platform_set_channel_map mixer_ctl_name:Playback Channel Map9
08-26 14:24:01.907   765  2141 D msm8974_platform: platform_set_channel_map: set mapping(1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0) for channel:2
08-26 14:24:01.908   765  2141 E msm8974_platform: platform_set_channel_map: Could not set ctl, error:-1 ch_count:2
08-26 14:24:01.910  1593  2291 D CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 4
08-26 14:24:01.910  1593  2291 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 160
08-26 14:24:01.910  1593  2291 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
08-26 14:24:01.911  1593  2291 D ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
08-26 14:24:01.921   788   788 I sensors-hal: batch:242, android.sensor.rotation_vector/111, period=200000000, max_latency=0
08-26 14:24:01.921   788   788 I sensors-hal: set_config:63, sample_period_ns is adjusted to 200000000 based on min/max delay_ns
08-26 14:24:01.922   788   788 I sensors-hal: batch:251, android.sensor.rotation_vector/111, period=200000000, max_latency=0 request completed
08-26 14:24:01.922   788  3273 I sensors-hal: ssc_conn_resp_cb:663, resp_value = 0
08-26 14:24:01.923  1593  1670 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 135634846; UID 10171; state: DISABLED
08-26 14:24:01.938   765  2141 D audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: exit
08-26 14:24:01.941   811  3651 E ANDR-IOP: io prefetch is disabled
08-26 14:24:01.941  1593  1670 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 135754954; UID 10171; state: ENABLED
08-26 14:24:01.941  1593  1757 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 143937733; UID 10171; state: ENABLED
08-26 14:24:01.944   811  3651 E ANDR-IOP: io prefetch is disabled
08-26 14:24:01.956   636   636 D Zygote  : Forked child process 5295
08-26 14:24:01.961  1593  1757 I ActivityManager: Start proc 5295:tud.jonass.gaugechecker/u0a171 for pre-top-activity {tud.jonass.gaugechecker/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
08-26 14:24:01.971  5295  5295 I er.gaugechecke: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-26 14:24:01.993  5295  5295 I er.gaugechecke: Unquickening 18 vdex files!
08-26 14:24:01.999  1104  1120 I adbd    : jdwp connection from 5295
08-26 14:24:02.010  1593  2291 D CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 4
08-26 14:24:02.010  1593  2291 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 160
08-26 14:24:02.010  1593  2291 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
08-26 14:24:02.012  1593  2291 D CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 4
08-26 14:24:02.012  1593  2291 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 160
08-26 14:24:02.012  1593  2291 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
08-26 14:24:02.049  5295  5295 I Perf    : Connecting to perf service.
08-26 14:24:02.068  5295  5295 D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
08-26 14:24:02.069  5295  5295 D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
08-26 14:24:02.086   916  1843 W DisplayIdentification: Invalid EDID: falling back to serial number due to missing display name.
08-26 14:24:02.086   916  1843 W DisplayIdentification: Invalid EDID: falling back to ASCII text due to missing serial number.
08-26 14:24:02.103  5295  5295 V PythonActivity: PythonActivity onCreate running
08-26 14:24:02.104  5295  5295 V PythonActivity: About to do super onCreate
08-26 14:24:02.104  5295  5295 V SDL     : Device: Navigator-500
08-26 14:24:02.104  5295  5295 V SDL     : Model: T21G
08-26 14:24:02.104  5295  5295 V SDL     : onCreate()
08-26 14:24:02.104  5295  5295 V PythonActivity: Did super onCreate
08-26 14:24:02.105  5295  5295 V SDL     : getting identifier
08-26 14:24:02.105  5295  5295 V SDL     : kind is layout and name lottie
08-26 14:24:02.105  5295  5295 V SDL     : result is 0
08-26 14:24:02.105  5295  5295 E er.gaugechecke: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
08-26 14:24:02.106  5295  5295 V SDL     : couldn't find lottie layout or animation, trying static splash
08-26 14:24:02.106  5295  5295 V SDL     : getting identifier
08-26 14:24:02.106  5295  5295 V SDL     : kind is drawable and name presplash
08-26 14:24:02.106  5295  5295 V SDL     : result is 2130771969
08-26 14:24:02.117   905  1211 W APM::AudioPolicyEngine: getDevicesForStrategy() unknown strategy: -1
08-26 14:24:02.117  1593  2852 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
08-26 14:24:02.121  5295  5295 V SDL     : asked to get string presplash_color
08-26 14:24:02.121  5295  5295 V SDL     : getting identifier
08-26 14:24:02.121  5295  5295 V SDL     : kind is string and name presplash_color
08-26 14:24:02.121  5295  5295 V SDL     : result is 2131034113
08-26 14:24:02.139  5295  5321 V PythonActivity: Ready to unpack
08-26 14:24:02.140  5295  5321 V pythonutil: Unpacking private app
08-26 14:24:02.140  5295  5321 V pythonutil: Data version is a49c915ad76ae5120c5a6efc465ef437757179c1
08-26 14:24:02.141  5295  5295 V SDL     : onStart()
08-26 14:24:02.144  5295  5295 V PythonActivity: onResume()
08-26 14:24:02.144  5295  5295 V SDL     : onResume()
08-26 14:24:02.145   765  1667 D audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: suspend_playback=true
08-26 14:24:02.146  5295  5321 V pythonutil: Unpacking /data/app/~~bQIy_797TjYpjqJaxYHWWg==/tud.jonass.gaugechecker-v6SQFJaGSmv5BQVv-VYdvw==/lib/arm64/libpybundle app
08-26 14:24:02.146  5295  5321 V pythonutil: Data version is a49c915ad76ae5120c5a6efc465ef437757179c1
08-26 14:24:02.167  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libSDL2.so
08-26 14:24:02.168  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
08-26 14:24:02.168  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
08-26 14:24:02.168  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libssl1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.168  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libpybundle.so
08-26 14:24:02.169  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libpython3.10.so
08-26 14:24:02.169  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libmain.so
08-26 14:24:02.169  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.169  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libffi.so
08-26 14:24:02.169  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libsqlite3.so
08-26 14:24:02.169  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Pattern libsqlite3\.so matched file libsqlite3.so
08-26 14:24:02.169  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libSDL2_image.so
08-26 14:24:02.170  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libSDL2.so
08-26 14:24:02.170  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
08-26 14:24:02.170  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
08-26 14:24:02.170  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libssl1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.170  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libpybundle.so
08-26 14:24:02.170  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libpython3.10.so
08-26 14:24:02.170  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libmain.so
08-26 14:24:02.170  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.170  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libffi.so
08-26 14:24:02.170  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Pattern libffi\.so matched file libffi.so
08-26 14:24:02.171  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libsqlite3.so
08-26 14:24:02.171  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libSDL2_image.so
08-26 14:24:02.171  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libSDL2.so
08-26 14:24:02.171  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
08-26 14:24:02.171  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
08-26 14:24:02.171  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libssl1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.172  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libpybundle.so
08-26 14:24:02.172  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libpython3.10.so
08-26 14:24:02.172  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libmain.so
08-26 14:24:02.172  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.172  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libffi.so
08-26 14:24:02.172  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libsqlite3.so
08-26 14:24:02.172  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libSDL2_image.so
08-26 14:24:02.173  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libSDL2.so
08-26 14:24:02.173  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
08-26 14:24:02.173  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
08-26 14:24:02.173  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libssl1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.173  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Pattern libssl.*\.so matched file libssl1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.173  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libpybundle.so
08-26 14:24:02.173  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libpython3.10.so
08-26 14:24:02.174  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libmain.so
08-26 14:24:02.174  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.174  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libffi.so
08-26 14:24:02.174  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libsqlite3.so
08-26 14:24:02.174  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libSDL2_image.so
08-26 14:24:02.174  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libSDL2.so
08-26 14:24:02.174  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
08-26 14:24:02.175  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
08-26 14:24:02.175  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libssl1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.175  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libpybundle.so
08-26 14:24:02.175  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libpython3.10.so
08-26 14:24:02.175  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libmain.so
08-26 14:24:02.175  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.175  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Pattern libcrypto.*\.so matched file libcrypto1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.175  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libffi.so
08-26 14:24:02.175  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libsqlite3.so
08-26 14:24:02.176  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libSDL2_image.so
08-26 14:24:02.176  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2\.so against libSDL2.so
08-26 14:24:02.176  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Pattern libSDL2\.so matched file libSDL2.so
08-26 14:24:02.176  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
08-26 14:24:02.176  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
08-26 14:24:02.177  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2\.so against libssl1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.177  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2\.so against libpybundle.so
08-26 14:24:02.177  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2\.so against libpython3.10.so
08-26 14:24:02.177  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2\.so against libmain.so
08-26 14:24:02.177  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.177  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2\.so against libffi.so
08-26 14:24:02.177  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2\.so against libsqlite3.so
08-26 14:24:02.177  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2\.so against libSDL2_image.so
08-26 14:24:02.178  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_image\.so against libSDL2.so
08-26 14:24:02.178  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_image\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
08-26 14:24:02.178  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_image\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
08-26 14:24:02.178  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_image\.so against libssl1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.178  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_image\.so against libpybundle.so
08-26 14:24:02.178  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_image\.so against libpython3.10.so
08-26 14:24:02.178  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_image\.so against libmain.so
08-26 14:24:02.178  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_image\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.178  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_image\.so against libffi.so
08-26 14:24:02.179  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_image\.so against libsqlite3.so
08-26 14:24:02.179  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_image\.so against libSDL2_image.so
08-26 14:24:02.179  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Pattern libSDL2_image\.so matched file libSDL2_image.so
08-26 14:24:02.179  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so against libSDL2.so
08-26 14:24:02.180  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
08-26 14:24:02.180  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
08-26 14:24:02.180  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so matched file libSDL2_mixer.so
08-26 14:24:02.180  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so against libssl1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.180  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so against libpybundle.so
08-26 14:24:02.181  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so against libpython3.10.so
08-26 14:24:02.181  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so against libmain.so
08-26 14:24:02.181  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.181  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so against libffi.so
08-26 14:24:02.181  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so against libsqlite3.so
08-26 14:24:02.181  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_mixer\.so against libSDL2_image.so
08-26 14:24:02.182  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so against libSDL2.so
08-26 14:24:02.182  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
08-26 14:24:02.183  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so matched file libSDL2_ttf.so
08-26 14:24:02.183  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
08-26 14:24:02.183  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so against libssl1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.183  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so against libpybundle.so
08-26 14:24:02.183  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so against libpython3.10.so
08-26 14:24:02.183  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so against libmain.so
08-26 14:24:02.183  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
08-26 14:24:02.183  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so against libffi.so
08-26 14:24:02.183  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so against libsqlite3.so
08-26 14:24:02.183  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libSDL2_ttf\.so against libSDL2_image.so
08-26 14:24:02.183  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: sqlite3
08-26 14:24:02.197  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: ffi
08-26 14:24:02.205  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: ssl1.1
08-26 14:24:02.230  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: crypto1.1
08-26 14:24:02.232  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: SDL2
08-26 14:24:02.260  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: SDL2_image
08-26 14:24:02.265  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: SDL2_mixer
08-26 14:24:02.271  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: SDL2_ttf
08-26 14:24:02.288  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: python3.5m
08-26 14:24:02.291  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Library loading error: dlopen failed: library "libpython3.5m.so" not found
08-26 14:24:02.292  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: python3.6m
08-26 14:24:02.293  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Library loading error: dlopen failed: library "libpython3.6m.so" not found
08-26 14:24:02.293  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: python3.7m
08-26 14:24:02.295  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Library loading error: dlopen failed: library "libpython3.7m.so" not found
08-26 14:24:02.295  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: python3.8
08-26 14:24:02.297  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Library loading error: dlopen failed: library "libpython3.8.so" not found
08-26 14:24:02.297  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: python3.9
08-26 14:24:02.299  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Library loading error: dlopen failed: library "libpython3.9.so" not found
08-26 14:24:02.299  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: python3.10
08-26 14:24:02.307  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loading library: main
08-26 14:24:02.310  5295  5295 V pythonutil: Loaded everything!
08-26 14:24:02.313  5295  5295 V SDL     : nativeSetupJNI()
08-26 14:24:02.314  5295  5295 V SDL     : AUDIO nativeSetupJNI()
08-26 14:24:02.314  5295  5295 V SDL     : CONTROLLER nativeSetupJNI()
08-26 14:24:02.329   635   736 W Netd    : SIMT: subsystem found in netlink event: qlog, ACTION: 3
08-26 14:24:02.340  5295  5295 V PythonActivity: Setting env vars for start.c and Python to use
08-26 14:24:02.341  5295  5295 V PythonActivity: Access to our meta-data...
08-26 14:24:02.342  5295  5295 I PythonActivity: Surface will NOT be transparent
08-26 14:24:02.359  5295  5318 I AdrenoGLES-0: QUALCOMM build                   : 47421dbee6, I139f36ad46
08-26 14:24:02.359  5295  5318 I AdrenoGLES-0: Build Date                       : 02/18/22
08-26 14:24:02.359  5295  5318 I AdrenoGLES-0: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.32.02.17
08-26 14:24:02.359  5295  5318 I AdrenoGLES-0: Local Branch                     : 
08-26 14:24:02.359  5295  5318 I AdrenoGLES-0: Remote Branch                    : 
08-26 14:24:02.359  5295  5318 I AdrenoGLES-0: Remote Branch                    : 
08-26 14:24:02.359  5295  5318 I AdrenoGLES-0: Reconstruct Branch               : 
08-26 14:24:02.359  5295  5318 I AdrenoGLES-0: Build Config                     : S P 10.0.7 AArch64
08-26 14:24:02.359  5295  5318 I AdrenoGLES-0: Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
08-26 14:24:02.364   916  1022 W ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER from uid=10171 pid=5295
08-26 14:24:02.364   916  1022 D PermissionCache: checking android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER for uid=10171 => denied (347 us)
08-26 14:24:02.367  5295  5318 I AdrenoGLES-0: PFP: 0x016ee197, ME: 0x00000000
08-26 14:24:02.369  5295  5295 V SDL     : surfaceCreated()
08-26 14:24:02.369  5295  5295 V SDL     : surfaceChanged()
08-26 14:24:02.369  5295  5295 V SDL     : Window size: 854x456
08-26 14:24:02.369  5295  5295 V SDL     : Device size: 854x480
08-26 14:24:02.375  5295  5295 V SDL     : Skip .. Surface is not ready.
08-26 14:24:02.415  1593  1753 I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed tud.jonass.gaugechecker/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity: +542ms
08-26 14:24:02.423  5295  5295 V SDL     : onWindowFocusChanged(): true
08-26 14:24:07.044  5295  5316 I er.gaugechecke: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
...
```

I have already tried a few things like changing Android API to match that of the device. However, I can't figure out the issue. I only noticed that when running the app in the emulator, there are many logcat entries with the package name *python* which are missing when running it on the device. Could this mean that python is not installed/supported on it? Or is there another problem?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I would like to suggest that you review this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70845537/kivy-app-working-on-pc-but-not-in-android/70849959#70849959). It may help you.

Comment: thanks for the tipp, I will try it as soon as I am on my dev PC again. However, I am using anaconda for package and environment management so I need to check all packages using anaconda instead of pip. But I will still try to see if specifying all packages required will fix my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem after noticing the following line in the log:

```
08-26 14:24:02.375  5295  5295 V SDL     : Skip .. Surface is not ready.
```

This brought me to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/m6sv42/works_fine_on_portrait_mode_but_struck_at_loading/). I noticed that the orientation in the *buildozer.spec* file was set to portrait. However, the Navigator 500 is using a landscape display. After changing this setting in the *buildozer.spec* file the app worked perfectly fine.